# phonegap-plugin-push integration with visual studio cordova

Tags: apple-push-notifications, visual-studio-cordova, ngcordova

I'm using `https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push` latest push plugin to integrate with cordova app using visual studio. In that plugin documentation, it has Android integration but not ios integration. Where can i find step by step ios integration with latest push plugin? I followed few articles but it didn't work..